# FTP to download file from one linux to another

Tags: linux, ftp, pure-ftpd

I would have an exam in few days about basic stuff on linux(I'm not familiar with linux therefore I'm studying for it). There would be two linux machines VM1 and VM2 on VMware, that connect via ethernet. I created on my PC this environment to prepare myself (two linux vms on vmware).  the first task is to ping between both machines-that's easy.in the second task they asked to run some `/start_ptpd`is it built in linux command? or is it mean to run some external program?

Comment: If something wrong with this post please let me know and I will edit, please don't downvote just like that without giving a reason.

Comment: The c question does not ask you to download anything to VM_2. It asks you to transfer a particular file from VM_2 to VM_1 using `ftp`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Yes, I understand that, I downloaded it to vm2 so I can transfer it to vm1 using ftp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exercise you posted must be run on a lab that is already set up, with VM_2 containing a FTP server and a custom shell script `start_ftp` that starts the FTP server. It won't work on a random Linux machine.

If you don't have access to such a lab, you can install any FTP server via the package manager of your Linux distribution, then try to catch up with the exercises.  But the best would be to ask your instructor.

Answer (score 0):

The default ftp client is `ftp`. Press <kbd>f</kbd>, then <kbd>t</kbd>, then <kbd>p</kbd> buttons in terminal, then press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you for response, I entered `ftp` as you said, and then it asked me to download it and I agreed, but now after it's installed I enter `./start_ftp` and it returns `No such file or directory`

Comment: Do you have an answer about it?